# Can I use LDAP for just authorization with Active Directory?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, ldapauth

I have to add **Active Directory authorization** in existing system. I have already been using Database Remote OS Authentication. I am in development phase right now. I have got various links for LDAP authorization and Authentication. As I want to implement only authorization so I would need only username for same. Moreover what parameters are required for initializing **HashTable** for **DirContext** in just **AD Authorization**

```
env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://" + domain); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "EXTERNAL"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
env.put("javax.security.sasl.server.authentication", "true");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userId + "@" + domain); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, securityToken);
ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

SearchResult srLdapUser = this.findAccountByAccountName(ctx, ldapSearchBase, userId);
```

Please suggest what do I pass in HashTable for just **Authorization through LDAP**, the above code is having some additional properties required for LDAP Authentication.

Comment: It depends but I'd suggest `Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);` to setup the environment for creating the initial context.

Comment: Can I get initial context without passing password here? @EricLavault

Comment: No need to pass anything in this call. Or if you meant without SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, it depends on SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION which is set twice in your code.